# How do I capture an 802.11 MPDU Delimiter field?

Tags: wireless, ieee-802.11

I would like to be able to capture an MPDU Delimiter that is part of an A-MPDU, and see the contents of those 4 bytes displayed on the image below.

[image]

Is there a way to do this in, for example, Wireshark and can someone provide the instructions and perhaps a .pcap file.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can purchase a hardware like **AirPcap**, which is a USB-based 802.11 radio designed to work effectively with Wireshark. It comes with drivers tuned to Wireshark and operates very well.

Be certain to monitor the correct RF(Radio Frequency) channel. For example, if the wireless network is set to channel 1 for the traffic you’re interested in, then configure Wireshark to monitor channel 1.